# Custom deserialization of polymorphic objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

Say I have the following structure, which I've serialized into a JSON.

```
public abstract class Vehicles {
    String make;
    String model;
    Map<Parts, int> partsList = new HashMap<>; // a list of parts for the vehicle and how much each part costs

    // Getters, setters, etc.
}

public class Cars extends Vehicles {
    int seats;

    // Getters, setters, etc.
}

public class Trucks extends Vehicles {
    int cargo;

    // Getters, setters, etc.
}
```

I then need a custom deserializer that can handle `partsList`, that will be reused each time a concrete child class gets deserialized. I've seen a few questions describing how to call a custom deserializer for child classes. I can't seem to find a solution that also allows the properties created in the superclass to be deserialized, avoiding repeating the deserialization code in each child subclass.

```
public class VehicleDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Vehicles> {
    protected VehicleDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        TypeReference<Map<Parts, int>> typeReference = new TypeReference() {};
        Map<Parts, int> parts = objectMapper.readValue(jsonNode.get("partsList").asText(), typeReference) // somehow need to feed this to partsList map when each subclass is deserialized -- THIS IS THE BIT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO.

        // code to call the appropriate subclass deserializer -- I don't need help with this bit...yet.
}
```

EDIT: to clarify, I think there have been plenty of examples of how to call the appropriate subclass deserializer. What I want to do is avoid repetitive code in each subclass deserializer for handling the map in the superclass.